# delete inefficient on Object, but efficient on DOM Element's data attributes, compared to null-out?

Tags: javascript, dom, v8, custom-data-attribute

It's known that `delete`ing a field from a JavaScript `Object` is a slow operation in V8 engine, compared to setting it to `null`, `undefined` or similar values: http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null

However, the performance difference between different methods seems to be minimal: http://jsperf.com/using-delete-on-dataset. It's even marginally faster than some other methods.

What's causing the inefficiency on "normal" Objects, and why doesn't it make any difference on dataset attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `delete` on an object whose properties are represented as fields stored at fixed offsets (like C struct, Java/C++ objects etc) will make the object use a hash table representation instead. Hash table look up with strings is much slower than simply reading memory at some fixed offset.

So if the object is already using a hash table representation for its properties, then doing delete doesn't affect performance.